# asssign value to object.variable formed dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have an object called "gameObj" and it has a variable called - "op1","op2",...
I want to assign some value to the variable of the object.
Here's my code :

```
    eval("gameObj.op"+i)
```

This gives me the values of the variable but when i try to assign some value, it gives an error saying:

"**ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment**"  by trying :

```
   eval("gameObj.op"+i) = 10;
```

even if i try to store it in a variable like :

```
  var temp =  val("gameObj.op"+i)
  temp = 10;
```

It changes the value of **temp** but not of gameObj.op1/2/3 [ie- the value of i]

How do i assign a value, say 10, to gameObj.op1 ?

Comment: What is `val`? and why `eval` when there's bracket notation?

Comment: What does mean 'val()'?

Comment: don't use eval. try `gameObj["op" + i]`

Comment: that's eval actually, mistake while coping...
Editted the question jow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't use `eval()`!**

Use bracket notation:

```
gameObj['op' + i] = 10;
```